# Reverse columns of spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to reverse columns of spreadsheet. Sample is "p227", "s121", "p117", "p252", "s215" in column "A1:E1". Values are random. I want to reverse this column like "s215", "p252","p117", "s121", "p227".

I tried `=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:E1),1,false))`. But output is `"s255", "s121", "p212", "p187", "p121"`. Values are sorted. This doesn't reverse columns. Is there way to solve this? Should I use GAS?

**Sample**

```
      A    B    C    D    E

1   p227 s121 p117 p252 s215
```

**Expected result**

```
      A    B    C    D    E

1   s215 p252 p117 s121 p227
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a general one

Method:

```
Transpose
Add row numbers
Sort descending by row number
Transpose
Remove row numbers
```

Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(TRANSPOSE(sort({row(indirect("1:"&columns(A1:E2))),transpose(A1:E2)},1,false)),"select * offset 1"))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

On reflection this would have been a bit neater, adding column numbers before transposing and avoiding the Indirect:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(TRANSPOSE(sort(transpose({COLUMN(A1:E2);A1:E2}),1,false)),"select * offset 1"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer worked perfectly. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:E1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E1)),0))
```

- SORTs using COLUMN numbers in descending order
- TRANSPOSE is needed as SORT only works on rows

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for the late reply. Your formula worked for me. I'm sorry I have already accepted Tom Sharpe's answer. But I can upvote.

Comment: @Elsa  Cheers

Comment: This is cool. To transpose the whole matrix, I used

`=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:E6),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E6)),0))`

Comment: Thank for the idea. I have the count of cells to be flipped stored in `A2`, so I tweaked your formula a bit.
`=SORT(TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(A1, 0, 0, 1, A2)), SEQUENCE(A2))`

Answer (score 2):

You can manually reassemble the columns into the order you like by using the array literal syntax:

```
={A:A,F:F,E:E,D:D,C:C,B:B}
```

Alternately, use [`QUERY()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) to re-order your columns.

```
QUERY(A:F, "SELECT A, F, E, D, C, B")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer works for me. I like simple query. But Tom Sharpe's answer was suitable for me. So I did only upvote. I'm sorry.

Comment: No worries and I appreciate the kind note. :)